# Different keyboard in same EditText - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I'm on Android.
I've got a list of EditText but when my keyboard is not visible and I clic on one EditText in the list my keyboard is not :

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
```

[With autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhlQZ.png)

I've just got letters and numbers on top :

[With numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbh5x.jpg)

(Image to illustrate)

I've got an array adapter to generate the list of EditText.
When I'm already with the Keyboard open and I change my EditText field the keyboard with autocomplete appear...

I really don't understand why I've got this result.

This is my EditText code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/ItemCaption"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/hint"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hint"
            android:textColor="@color/textWhite">
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

When I clic the first time I can see the autocomplete propositions but it quickly desappear and then the numbers display.

So if somebody have an answer to my problem or just some hints I'll be very grateful.

**Edit 1**

Some screenshots

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvoh1.png)

[Auto complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOCS0.png)

[Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi97b.png)